# php: property inheritance on nested class structure

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

It's not clear to me how class inheritance is implemented in php 5.4.7 (almost old! I know!).
Consider this example:

```
Class ClassA {
    public $property = array();
    function __construct() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassA.construct";
    }
    public function SetA() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassA.Set";
    }
}

Class ClassB extends ClassA {
    function __construct() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.construct";
    }
    function SetB() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.Set";
    }
}
```

If I call in sequence

```
$classA = new ClassA();
$classA->SetA();
$classB = new ClassB();
$classB->SetB();
print_r($classB->property);
```

*My* expected behavior is to have...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ClassA.construct
    [1] => ClassA.Set
    [2] => ClassB.construct
    [3] => ClassB.Set
)
```

...but I obtain instead...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ClassB.construct
    [1] => ClassB.Set
)
```

So, what's wrong on my side?
How can I add element from a Child to an array defined on Parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, parent constructors aren't called automatically, to get your behaviour you need to do the following:

```
Class ClassB extends ClassA {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.construct";
    }
    function SetB() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.Set";
    }
}
```

And, at most, you'll get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => ClassA.construct
    [2] => ClassB.construct
    [3] => ClassB.Set
)
```

as `SetA()` is never invoked

When you invoked the sequence you described, `$classA` and `$classB` are two different instances, so you will never get what you expect.

To get what you want, you need to do this:

```
$classB = new ClassB();
$classB->SetB();
$classB->SetA();
print_r($classB->property);
```

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand how inheritance works in general: `$classA` is an instance of `ClassA` and has nothing to do with the instance `$classB` of `ClassB` you have generated.

An instance of `ClassB` inherits all public and protected properties and methods of `ClassA` but as long as you don't use them, you will not see them.

And all instances, whether from `ClassA` or from `ClassB`, are unrelated to each other, they only have the same "template" but each has its own property values.

Comment: on other hands there's no possibility for classB to access to values of $property defined on classA. Isn't it?

Comment: @StefanoRadaelli Yes there is, if the property if public or protected or if there is a setter in `ClassA` to set a private property. However, the property is still specific for that instance of `ClassB`, it does not change anything in other objects of `ClassA` or `ClassB`.

Answer (score 1):

That's really simple: why did you expect the parent constructor to run if you forgot to call it in `ClassB`? According to https://3v4l.org/keJ2a, this has not changed since PHP 5.0.0 and still works the same in recent PHP 7 versions

Comment: Also you need to call `SetA()` somewhere in your class B instance to get `[1] => ClassA.Set` in your array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the expected result then you need to change the code as per the PHP oops concept this will not work as you want.

**You Updated Code**

```
Class ClassA {
    public $property = array();
    function __construct() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassA.construct";
        $this->SetA();
    }
    public function SetA() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassA.Set";
    }
}

Class ClassB extends ClassA {
    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();//invoke parent constructor       
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.construct";
    }
    function SetB() {
        $this->property[] = "ClassB.Set";
    }
}


$classB = new ClassB();
$classB->SetB();
print_r($classB->property);
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ClassA.construct
    [1] => ClassA.Set
    [2] => ClassB.construct
    [3] => ClassB.Set
)
```

When `parent::__construct();` invokes then it maintains `$property` array variable for child class also.

**Note:** As we know OOPS concept, every object has a different instance.

Comment: That's clear. But in this case ClassA->SetA() method cannot be called upon certain condition.
My goal is to (#1) instanciate ClassA with some values from __construct, (#2) then call main.php -> ClassA->SetA() if "a certain condition is true" and (#3) then to allow to ClassB to get all the values of $property already set from ClassA.

Comment: Yes, you are right but can not go against rules. Also, we can not merge two instances into a single one.